# make UITabBar without adding in appDelegate file

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, uitabbar

I am making an application which will have 3 pages

1. Login Page - first page after the app loads
2. **My First Page**- when user successfully logs in then he comes into this page.This page
   contains a UITabBar with two UITabBarItems. The first one is connected to

   My firstPage

   and the other one to My Second Page.
3. **My Second Page** - this is another UIViewController.

I have made the login page but I am unable to find the solution to UITabBar adding in My First Page

Please help me out

Comment: You can add tabbar at appDelegate, keep tabbar hidden for login page, and not hidden for rest of viewControllers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define 
AppDelegate.h

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UITabBarController *tabBarController;
```

in AppDelegate.m

didFinishLaunchingWithOptions

```
self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
self.tabBarController.delegate=self;
self.tabBarController.selectedIndex=0;
self.tabBarController.delegate=self;


 - (BOOL)tabBarController:(UITabBarController *)tabBarController shouldSelectViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController{

return YES;
}
```

now when you get success login write below code in that method

```
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UIViewController *viewController1 = [[FirstViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"FirstViewController" bundle:nil];
    UIViewController *viewController2 = [[SecondViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SecondViewController" bundle:nil];

    delegate.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc] init];
    delegate.tabBarController.selectedIndex = 0;
    delegate.tabBarController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:viewController1, viewController2, nil];
    delegate.tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleCoverVertical;
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:delegate.tabBarController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out,

suppose this is LoginViewController.m

```
-(IBAction)loginButtonClicked:(id)sender
{
    [self createTabBarView];
}

//Create TabBar View here 
-(void)createTabBarView
{
     NSMutableArray *tabItems = [NSMutableArray array];
     UIViewController *firstViewController = [[FirstViewController alloc] init];;
     firstViewController = @"First View";
     firstViewController = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:0];
      [tabItems addObject:firstViewController];
      UIViewController *secondViewController = [[SecondViewController alloc] init];;
      secondViewController = @"Second View";
      secondViewController = [[UITabBarItem alloc]initWithTabBarSystemItem:UITabBarSystemItemContacts tag:1];
      [tabItems addObject:secondViewController];
      self.tabBarController = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];
      self.tabBarController.viewControllers = tabItems;    
      self.tabBarController.modalTransitionStyle = UIModalTransitionStyleFlipHorizontal;
      [self presentModalViewController:tabBarController animated:YES];
}
```

Thanks,

Nikhil.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using interface builder?
From my point of view, I'd rather like to use programmatic way to implement it.

```
//In the appDidFinishLaunch method

    BOOL loggedIn = [[NSUserDefault standDefault]boolForKey:"userlogin"];

    if(loggedIn)
    {

        //Setup your UITabbarViewController

    }
    else
    {

        //Setup your loginView Controller
    }
```

After login in LogInViewController

```
- (void)didLogin
{

   YourAppDelegate *delegate = [UIApplication shareApplication].delegate;  

   [delegate.window addSubView:self.tabBarViewController.view];

   [delegate.window removeSubView:self.view]

   //Other Config

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should create Tabbar at place where you can identify that login is successfully done. This method should be part of your loginViewController.
Create a function like below to create a Tabbar and present it over loginController.

```
-(void) createTabBarController
{
     UITabBarController *tabBar = [[UITabBarController alloc]init];

     UIViewController *firstViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
     UINavigationController *firstNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:firstViewController];
     firstNavController.tabBarItem.title=@"First Controller";
     firstNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];

     UIViewController *secondViewController = [[[UIViewController alloc] init]autorelease];
     UINavigationController *secondNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:secondViewController];
     secondNavController.tabBarItem.title=@"First Controller";
     secondNavController.tabBarItem.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"first.png"];

     [tabBar setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObject:firstNavController,secondNavController,nil]];    
     [firstNavController release];
     [secondNavController release];

     [self presentModalViewController: tabBar];
     [tabBar release];
}
```